# In PL/SQL, can %ROWTYPE be re-used for another %ROWTYPE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, variable-declaration, rowtype

Or does it behave like a variable for which we have to use %TYPE?

```
declare
row1 emp%rowtype;
row2 row1%rowtype;
--row3 row1%type;
begin
null;
end;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When you run your test PL/SQL block from your example there, do you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use both `%rowtype` and `%type`, apparently both behave identically.

Comment: Yes, but why rowtype and then another rowtype based on it works...!?

Comment: I'm just as surprised as you ;-)